# Generate classes in compile time with java and maven

Tags: java, junit

I have a project that have one junit test class, i need to generate multiple junit classes in compile time, what exactly i want to do is have the same junit class but with a change in a property value.

I could not accomplish this in runtime, this shold be done in compile time.

I tried to see the aspectj but could not find how to generate classes in compile time.

is that even possible in java ??

Comment: Can you use an @Parameterized test instead? e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/

Comment: AOP will definitely not help you here. Nor should you have Maven anywhere near your running application. Look at [Junit rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) or at the `@Parameterized` suggestion in @Benoît's answer

Comment: I smell a code smell.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your sugesstion, but @paramterized and these things will not work, we are running our test on amazon device farm, and it seems they do not support these junit functionalitites

Comment: What i did so far, a job that create the class as text files and then build the project, but if i can accomplish this with aop compile time it will be better

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Parameterized as stated by Andy, or inherit from a base Test class :

```
abstract class CommonTests {
    @Test
    public void testA() { 
        assertEquals(1, getValue()); 
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testB() { ...}
    ....
    abstract int getValue();
}

class Test1 extends CommonTests {
   int getValue() { return 1;}
}

class Test2 extends CommonTests {
   int getValue() { return 2;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this wont work with us we want to generate the class dynamically, and as the above comment, aws device farm do not support these functionalitites of junit.
what i really need is to use aop to generate classes at compile time, but this seems to be not possible in java

Comment: Ok. No problem. Maybe you could edit your question to give a better description of your needs. It might give to me or other users a better understanding of your requirements